# How to get create-react-app test in a typescript (babel) based monorepo

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, monorepo

I've taken the example at 
https://github.com/serhii-havrylenko/monorepo-babel-ts-lerna-starter, (lerna, yarn workspaces, typescript and babel transpilation based monorepo) and added a create-react-app based app to the project.

After some tweaking, I've got `yarn build` and `yarn start` working correctly in the UI project, pulling in (successfully) the modules defined in the other packages.  The most significant change was switching from typescript path and baseUrl configurations to find the modules and instead using workspace links.

My problem is that I'm failing to get `yarn test` working in the UI project.  When I run it, I get:

```
FAIL src/App.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '@taxi/login-form' from 'App.tsx'

    > 1 | import { LoginForm } from '@taxi/login-form';
        | ^
      2 | import React, { Component } from 'react';
      3 | import './App.css';
      4 |

      at Resolver.resolveModule (../../node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:221:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.tsx:1:1)
```

This error is in a component that builds successfully and loads in the browser.

I've tried everything that I can think of to get jest to correctly load this module.

Rather than paste in lots of file contents here, I've posted my forked repo here: https://github.com/ggascoigne/monorepo-babel-ts-lerna-starter.  The readme has explicit steps listed to reproduce the problem.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: so many questions like this, I want to know too and none of the questions have answers